# jira-python search_issues() returns empty list

Tags: python, jira

```
from jira.client import JIRA
jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('user', 'password'))    
issues = jira.search_issues('project=titan')
print issues
```

[]

Following tutorials on accessing jira thru python. Logging in and other methods work fine but I can't get this method to return anything. If I put != instead of = I still get nothing. Any ideas? Real user and password is used. There are many issues and I can access them individually like:
    issue = jira.issue('TITAN-nnn')

jira version = 6.1.3
python version = 2.7.3

Comment: Enter the JQL in the browser and see what JIRA changes it to. Perhaps TITAN in all caps?

Answer (score 1):

Turn on debugging to see what happens:

```
import httplib
httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel= 1
```

Example connecting to the public JIRA:

```
>>> from jira.client import JIRA
>>> import httplib
>>> httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel= 1
>>> options = {
...     'server': 'https://jira.atlassian.com'
... }
>>> jira = JIRA(options)
>>> issues = jira.search_issues('project=JSD')
send: 'GET /rest/api/2/search?jql=project%3DJSD&startAt=0&maxResults=50 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: jira.atlassian.com\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.5 Darwin/13.0.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress\r\nAccept: */*\r\nX-Atlassian-Token: nocheck\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: nginx
header: Date: Wed, 26 Feb 2014 06:17:33 GMT
header: Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Connection: keep-alive
header: X-AREQUESTID: 377x7779615x3
header: X-ASEN: TestSEN
header: X-AUSERNAME: anonymous
header: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform
header: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
header: X-Robots-Tag: noarchive
header: Vary: Accept-Encoding
header: Content-Encoding: gzip
header: Set-Cookie: __atl_path=172.24.36.107.1393395450345419; path=/; expires=Sat, 24-Feb-24 06:17:30 GMT; domain=.atlassian.com
header: Set-Cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=AKVY-YUFR-9LM7-97AB|ecb611160886e0c356f238dc407f015375fffb40|lout; Path=/
header: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=DA80ADFD3371C4FA2B06F54037B48BB9; Path=/
>>> print issues
[<JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-361', id=u'319731'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-360', id=u'319715'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-359', id=u'319714'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-358', id=u'319676'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-357', id=u'319459'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-356', id=u'319436'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-355', id=u'319225'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-354', id=u'319201'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-352', id=u'319192'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-351', id=u'319189'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-350', id=u'319177'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-349', id=u'318912'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-348', id=u'318911'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-347', id=u'318846'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-346', id=u'318840'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-345', id=u'318539'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-344', id=u'318537'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-343', id=u'318492'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-342', id=u'318459'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-340', id=u'318303'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-338', id=u'318128'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-337', id=u'318039'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-336', id=u'318021'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-335', id=u'318020'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-334', id=u'318014'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-333', id=u'317923'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-332', id=u'317908'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-331', id=u'317829'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-330', id=u'317825'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-329', id=u'317821'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-328', id=u'317803'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-327', id=u'317801'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-326', id=u'317800'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-325', id=u'317798'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-324', id=u'317769'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-323', id=u'317747'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-322', id=u'317646'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-321', id=u'317603'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-320', id=u'317601'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-319', id=u'317599'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-318', id=u'317541'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-317', id=u'317499'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-316', id=u'317462'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-315', id=u'317460'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-314', id=u'317440'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-313', id=u'317436'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-312', id=u'317358'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-311', id=u'317355'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-310', id=u'317353'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'JSD-309', id=u'317281'>]
```

You'll see the `send:` which tells you the JQL that gets outputed with your request. Should give you an idea of what is going on to try to troubleshoot.

This was with `Python 2.7.5` and `JIRA 6.2` however I also tried with `Jira 6.0.7` and it worked.

Also, you can try to adjust your JQL to be the full Project Name instead of the key, if it includes spaces wrap it in quotes.

Comment: Yes it looks like your example but the list is still empty. where's your list of issues you got back? I've tried everything, double quotes, single quotes, escaped quotes, upper case, lower case, mixed. Never get anything returned.

Comment: I updated with it printing out the output. Is this happening just to your local instance or if you try to hit Atlassians JIRA like I did is it happening as well?

Comment: It only happens on my instance of Jira, works ok to Atlassians as in your example.

Comment: And if you hit the URL that is listed beside the `send: 'get` to your local jira in your browser, does it return results?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You mean paste this in bowser and push enter?      /rest/api/2/search?jql=+%22Project%22+%3D+TITAN+&startAt=0&maxResults=3 HTTP/1 ... - did not match any documents.

Comment: Disregard previous comment, I put the whole url then got: a 404 error Atlassian page saying "Oh,it seems that we've lost a page.
Maybe you should raise an issue?

Comment: Sorry not sure what's going on if `ira.issue('TITAN-nnn')` works but `jira.search_issues('project=titan')` doesn't. Try logging an Atlassian support ticket as they may be able to provide additional troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

You do `jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth = ('user', password'))`, but have you defined options elsewhere? Your options should define the server before you call jira = JIRA(.....etc like so:

```
options { 'server' : 'http://jira.atlassian.com' }
```

and then your call should look like:

```
jira = JIRA(options = options, basic_auth = ('user', 'password'))
```

Unless you have done that already, I suggest you do that and see if it works. If not, try spelling titan the same exact way it is spelled in jira.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
projects = jira.projects()
keys = sorted([project.key for project in projects])
for key_val in keys:
    issues = jira.search_issues('project='+key_val,maxResults=500000)
    for issue_names in issues:
        print 'issue id - ',issue_names
```